# prevent children from inheriting transformation css3

Tags: css

I have a `div` that i'm tranforming (scale and translate), but inside that `div` i have another `div`. Now i would to see that the inner `div` isnt affected by the transformation of its parent, in other words. I would like for the inner `div` to not scale like his parent does.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="rightsection">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle">
          <div class="large">
            <img src="assets/images/rightpanel_expanded.png" alt="map" title="map"/>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <p>Check if your friends are going!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#rightsection:hover {
    -moz-transform:scale(2.16,2.8) translate(-80px,-53px);
    -webkit-transform:scale(2.16,2.8) translate(-80px,-53px);
    -o-transform:scale(2.16,2.8) translate(-80px,-53px);
    -ms-transform:scale(2.16,2.8) translate(-80px,-53px);
    transform:scale(2.16,2.8) translate(-80px,-53px)
}
```

So the problem is, when i scale `#rightsection`, the `img` gets scaled to, but i would like to keep the image on its original size.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should move the inner div out of the outer div.

Comment: Could you recreate what you have so far on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Your image can be from http://dummyimage.com/.

Comment: I have recreated it, it can be found here: jsfiddle.net/ecbVH. As you can see the image should be 578x329 but it is waaay bigger, just hover over the element to see the result

Answer (score 3):

Here is it what worked for me..

I used opposite transition for children. Then it was stable

```
.logo {
    background: url('../images/logo-background.png') no-repeat;
    width: 126px;
    height: 127px;
    margin-top:-24px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;

}
a.logo span{
    display: block;
    width: 126px;
    height: 127px;
    background: url('../images/logo-bismi.png') no-repeat;
    z-index: 20;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;    

}
a.logo:hover span{
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
}
a.logo {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;        
}
a.logo:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(360deg); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as usual. Set "transform: none" to all of children.

```
.children1,
.children2,
.childrenN {
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
```

Comment: That prevents nesting of transforms, doesn't it?

Comment: How should this work? I can't reproduce this on either absolute or relative-positioned children. Here's how I tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/NPC42/XSHmJ/

Comment: (note: I am trying with transform: rotate(), perhaps it doesn't apply?)

Comment: The problem is that children elements do NOT rotate WITH "transform: none;" property or WITHOUT it. The parent element is rotated, so unrotated child seems to be rotated too. So your possible solutions may be: 1) inverse children element rotation (for ex, if the parent has rotate(30deg), then child must have rotate(-30deg) ). 2) Use absolute position, so that children overlaid their parents, but were not contained in them.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 70px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That isn't preventing the inheritance, it's just undoing it with a double negative.

Comment: If transform: rotate(30deg); then transform: none; not working. But works transform: rotate(-30deg); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you can make the children of the parent positioned in the 3D-space by set `transform-style: preserve-3d;` in parent, then you can apply transform-functions in **reverse** order of parent to children elements that want to keep front.

```css
.parent {
  transform: rotateX(33deg) rotateY(66deg) rotateZ(99deg);
  /* Notice! You should make the children of the parent positioned in the 3D-space. */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 4px solid darkblue;
}

.child {
  /* Notice! You should apply the opposite order of rotations (transform functions) from the parent element. */
  transform: rotateZ(-99deg) rotateY(-66deg) rotateX(-33deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I'am a child want keep front.
  </div>
</div>
```

See: [css - How to prevent children from inheriting 3d transformation CSS3? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701038/how-to-prevent-children-from-inheriting-3d-transformation-css3/59701039#59701039)

Answer (score 0):

This should work as a general rule in most cases.

You can apply the same rule to the other transform methods.

```
.parent {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.parent > * {
  /* to cover elements like <span> */
  display: block; 
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```