# Rotate only the Border using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to rotate only the border using css but the font-icon is also rotating. How do I stop the rotation of the icon and make only the border?

CSS:

```
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px dashed #000;
 -webkit-animation-name: Rotate;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
 -moz-animation-name: Rotate;
 -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
 -ms-animation-name: Rotate;
 -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
 -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.play {
padding: 20px 30px;
font-size: 56px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Rotate
{
 from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
 to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes Rotate
{
 from{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
 to{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes Rotate
{
 from{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg);}
 to{-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
   <div class="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong with this code?

[DEMO JSFIDDEL](https://jsfiddle.net/yp7je9n2/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045140/prevent-children-from-inheriting-transformation-css3

Comment: Great. Let me have a look.

Comment: @cssGEEK your technique won't work on rotation. I have already tried that but thanks.

Comment: As everybody suggested, don't rotate the node that contains content. If you don't want to add extra DOM nodes, it can be resolved with pseudo-elements. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjaVmG

Answer (score 18, accepted):

rotating parent will rotate child as well so it's better to style border separately like here

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle .border {
  /* content: ''; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
  -webkit-animation-name: Rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: Rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-name: Rotate;
  -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.play {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 56px;
}
.stop {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes Rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes Rotate {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  PS: The icon loading is a bit slow. Wait until it shows up.
</p>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="stop">Stop me please</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code in your answer not in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="button-container">
   <i class="fa fa-play button-icon"></i>
   <div class="button-border"></div>
</div>
```

You may find an updated version of your sample here 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yp7je9n2/12/)

Comment: Thank You. I got it working with Lucian's code.