# Can I make this shape with CSS?

Tags: html, css

i want to make a shape like this using CSS 3, but i couldn't rotate the border like this.

[image: wanted]

Is there any way to make this using css only?

i thought about a class like this:

```
border: 0px solid #1C6EA4;
border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
```

but i didn't get the wanted result

UPDATE:

in found this but it still needs some edits to be like the wanted one

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 14% 66%, 0% 30%);
clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 14% 66%, 0% 30%);
```

[image: result]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810615/3855179

Comment: I would recommend this page: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: That shape would probably need an SVG.

Comment: @Wimanicesir i used this website  but i still need to do some edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with CSS only:

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
}

.image-container {
  border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg) translateX(100px) translateY(50px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-container img {
  transform: rotate(20deg) translateX(-100px);
}
```

```html
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
    </div>
  </div>
```