# sKew Issue: How to transform with sKew

Tags: transform, skew

I'm new in css sKew, I made my `<li>ALL</li>` transform to -45deg when I did this my Text is too rotated, But I want to keep my text as Straight, but it also rotated.
ScreenShot.

PSD
[image: PSD image:]

My Design
[image: My Design:]

How Can I will fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `skew()` you can put your text inside a `div` and use this CSS

```css
.container {
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">All</div>
</div>
```

This should work with a `<li>` too.

If you keep the text inside you need to "undo" the tranformation, as showed above.

Otherwise you could put the text outside the `<li>` and this will be not affected by the `transform:skew()`.

(Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045140/prevent-children-from-inheriting-transformation-css3))