# How to prevent children from inheriting 3d transformation CSS3?

Tags: css, css-transforms

How to prevent children from inheriting 3d transformation CSS3?

I have a parent div and a child div, now I want to let parent using 3d transformation and the child div keep front.

Example:

```css
.parent {
  transform: rotateX(33deg) rotateY(66deg) rotateZ(99deg);

  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 4px solid darkblue;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I'am a child want keep front.
  </div>
</div>
```

Set contrarotation, or set none transform is no effect.

```css
.parent {
  transform: rotateX(33deg) rotateY(66deg) rotateZ(99deg);

  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 4px solid darkblue;
}

.child {
  transform: rotateX(-33deg) rotateY(-66deg) rotateZ(-99deg);

  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I'am a child want keep front.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should make the children of the parent positioned in the 3D-space by set `transform-style: preserve-3d;` in parent, then you can apply transform-functions in **reverse** order of parent to children elements that want to keep front.

```css
.parent {
  transform: rotateX(33deg) rotateY(66deg) rotateZ(99deg);
  /* Notice! You should make the children of the parent positioned in the 3D-space. */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 4px solid darkblue;
}

.child {
  /* Notice! You should apply the opposite order of rotations (transform functions) from the parent element. */
  transform: rotateZ(-99deg) rotateY(-66deg) rotateX(-33deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I'am a child want keep front.
  </div>
</div>
```

TL;DR

Why we should use **reverse** order?

According to [transform-function - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function) :

Transform-functions using **matrix multiplication** combin in order from right to left, and matrix multiplication doesn't satisfy the **commutative law**, so we should use **reverse** order to counteract parent's transforms.

Example:

let `rotateX(33deg) = matrixA, rotateY(66deg) = matrixB, rotateZ(99deg) = matrixC`

We can get `rotateX(-33deg) = matrixA^-1, rotateY(-66deg) = matrixB^-1, rotateZ(-99deg) = matrixC^-1` (See: [Invertible matrix - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix), [Rotation matrix - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions))

We can calculate the points, rotate with parent, of children `rotatedPoint = originPoint * matrixA * matrixB * matrixC`.

We want to make those points in its origin position, so we should do `resultPoint = rotatedPoint * matrixC^-1 * matrixB^-1 * matrixA^-1` because matrix multiplication doesn't satisfy the **commutative law**.